# Spring Boot doesn't render views properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've always build Spring MVC web application configuring them by myself until I've been told about this Spring Boot that helps you configuring/initialising your application. 
So I decided to give it a try and I created a new project using Spring Boot. I followed all the steps in order to make it work with a main class a controller and all the required dependencies. When I run the application it starts and it responds also to the HTTP requests. The problem occurs when I try to return a view. It simply returns the view as a normal html file without rendering all the Spring tags.
Let me show you what I've done:

This is the directory tree of the project:

[image]

I created a directory webapp/WEB-INF/view in which i put the jsp files corresponding to the views. So far I have just one, helloWord.jsp that is quite simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>Hello ${name}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

*SpringBootHelloWorldApplication* is the main class, containing the following code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.example.springboothelloworld"})
public class SpringBootHelloWorldApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

*ApplicationCofigurerAdapter* configures the InternalResourceViewResolver in this way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationConfigurerAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

*HelloWorldController* is the controller that handles all the HTTP requests

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    @ResponseBody
    public String hello(){
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello/{name}")
    public String helloView(@PathVariable("name") String name, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "helloWorld";
    }
}
```

And inside the *application.properties* I put these lines but I don't know if I really need them cause they are already present inside the ApplicationConfigurerAdapter.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
```

When I send this HTTP GET request: *http://localhost:8080/home/hello/Stefano*

It returns this:

[image]

Which is of course an unexpected result.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to make it work. I had to install maven on my macOS and then run the following command in order to remove the *target* folder, compile the code and also package it (in my case in a JAR format).

```
mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage
```

After this I can execute the JAR file using the following command:

```
java -jar target/file_name.jar
```

At this point (if everything went fine) my web app is now running on localhost:8080. 
I still don't know how to make it work on IntelliJ also because in this way I don't know how to debug it.